# ¿Cómo puedo crear una web api en .net, que en la misma url reciba parámetros diferentes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Necesito crear una web api que a través de POST, y en la misma URL, a veces reciba un parámetro(en el body) y a veces otro.
Sucede que estoy utilizando un Gateway GSM que hace un push de todos los eventos SMS a la misma URL(no me permite definir una para cada evento), por lo que en la misma ruta recibo JSONs diferentes.
Esto es lo que quiero hacer:

```
[HttpPost, Route("~/api/recibido")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(SmsDeliveryStatus resul)
```

JSON que recibe:

```
{
   "sn":"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
   "sms_result":[
      {
         "port":1,
         "number":"10086",
         "time":"2016-07-1201:46:02",
         "status":"DELIVERED",
         "count":1,
         "succ_count":1,
         "ref_id":215,
         "imsi":"460004642148063"
      }
   ]
}
    
[HttpPost, Route("~/api/recibido")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(ReceivedSms sms)
```

JSON que recibe:

```
{
   "sn":"da00-0030-1901-2817",
   "sms":[
      {
         "incoming_sms_id":1,
         "port":1,
         "number":"6717",
         "smsc":"+8613800757511",
         "timestamp":"2016-07-12 15:46:18",
         "text":"test"
      }
   ]
}
```

Los JSON que recibe la api son diferentes, y pensé que el controlador los rutearía automáticamente de acuerdo a su tipo, pero no sucede así.
¿Podría crear un único método que reciba un objeto, y luego deserializarlo y castearlo?
Le estaría muy agradecido a quien pudiera brindarme alguna orientación.

P/D: Es mi primera pregunta en este sitio y como se habrán dado cuenta, recién estoy arrancando con esto. Pido disculpas anticipadas si mi pregunta es muy tonta o poco clara.

Comment: Muéstranos ejemplos de los json

Comment: Estimado Arriel: los he agregado a la pregunta.

Comment: Ya intentaste recibir un objeto? `public IHttpActionResult Post(object sms)`

Comment: Estimado @PabloGutiérrez: Si, intenté recibir un objeto y funciona bien; pero no sabía como deserializarlo(me faltaba hacer un ToString() del objeto).
Hice varias pruebas y creo que encontré algo que podría funcionar, recién lo estoy probando:

public IHttpActionResult Post(object obj){
var respuesta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReceivedSms >(obj.ToString());

Creo que podría  deserializarlo en función de lo que recibo.
Otro usuario me ha brindado una posible solución que también me parece muy interesante.
En breve compartiré aquí como lo resolví.
¡Mucísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Juan, si en realidad:

1. No tienes opción y todos los JSON van a la misma url, y
2. No tienes forma de separar los requests dependiendo del objeto,

Entonces podrías combinar los posibles objetos que llegan al Post del controlador. Imagino que tienes la clase `SmsDeliveryStatus` definida algo así:

```
public class SmsDeliveryStatus {
    public string sn { get; set; } 
    public List<SmsResult> sms_result { get; set; } 
  }

public class SmsResult    {
    public int port { get; set; } 
    public string number { get; set; } 
    public string time { get; set; } 
    public string status { get; set; } 
    public int count { get; set; } 
    public int succ_count { get; set; } 
    public int ref_id { get; set; } 
    public string imsi { get; set; } 
}
```

Y tu clase `ReceivedSms`

```
public class ReceivedSms {
    public string sn { get; set; } 
    public List<Sms> sms { get; set; } 
}

public class Sms    {
    public int incoming_sms_id { get; set; } 
    public int port { get; set; } 
    public string number { get; set; } 
    public string smsc { get; set; } 
    public string timestamp { get; set; } 
    public string text { get; set; } 
}
```

Tal vez quieras unificar el objeto que recibes en el POST para cubrir ambos escenarios y tomar decisiones basados en lo que llega.

Por ejemplo

```
public class SmsRequest
{
    public string sn { get; set; } 
    [JsonProperty("sms")]          
    public List<Sms> ReceivedSms {get;set:}
    [JsonProperty("sms_result")]
    public List<SmsResult> SmsDeliveryStatus {get;set:}
}
```

Y en el controlador verificar si alguno viene null.

```
[HttpPost, Route("~/api/recibido")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(SmsRequest sms)
{
    if (sms.ReceivedSms != null){
        
        // hacer lo relacionado con ReceivedSms

     } else if(sms.SmsDeliveryStatus != null){
              // hacer lo relacionado con SmsDeliveryStatus {get;set;}
            }
      else {
           // Manejar el caso que ambos sean null o regresar un error, si es el caso
          return BadRequest();
        }
}
```

De esta manera, siempre recibes la propiedad `sn`, y una sola lista de objetos, dependiendo del json.

Inténtalo y nos cuentas cómo te fue.

Comment: Estimado @Arriel:
Te comento que no conocía la anotación "JsonProperty" ¡y me parece muy interesante! Ya estoy googleando al respecto. 
No puedo definir una URL para cada request porque el aparato que envía los SMS (marca Dinstar) no lo permite.
¡Tu solución me simplificaría bastante las cosas!
Lo voy a probar y ya te comentaré como me fue. 
¡Te agradezco mucho que te hayas tomado la molestia de enseñarme todo esto!
Muchas gracias nuevamente.
Saludos.
Juan